# How to resolve the error of uploading the image on server?

Tags: android, vb.net, web-services, soap

I'm writing it again, i'm developing an app in which user click a picture through image and image will be stored in sdcard then I have choose the picture from image view and send that picture to the server. I have convert my image into the byte array and then encoded it in Base64 string format but when i try to send that image to the server it give me an error of soap fault. Here's the my code of android device:

public void doneImage(){

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    byte[] imagebyte = out.toByteArray();

    String jp = caption.getText().toString();//for fetching the path of selected image path.//

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    String strBase64 =  Base64.encode(imagebyte);

    PropertyInfo addProp = new PropertyInfo();
    addProp.setName("imgdata");
    addProp.setValue(strBase64);
    addProp.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(addProp);


    PropertyInfo addProp1 = new PropertyInfo();
    addProp1.setName("FileName");
    addProp1.setValue(jp);
    addProp1.setType(String.class);
    Request.addProperty(addProp1);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE aht=new HttpTransportSE(URL);

      try
       {
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success" +response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
      catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            caption.setText(e.toString());
            //return null;
            //Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
} 




   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

      switch (requestCode) {
     case PICK_IMAGE:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

       String filePath = null;

      try {
       // OI FILE Manager
       String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

       // MEDIA GALLERY
        String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

        if (selectedImagePath != null) {
        filePath = selectedImagePath;

        caption.setText(selectedImagePath);

         } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
        filePath = filemanagerstring;

        caption.setText(filemanagerstring);
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
               }

    if (filePath != null) {
       decodeFile(filePath);
     } else {
        bitmap = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        }
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```

And at the server side I have used vb.net web service. And code is:

_
    Public Function UploadImage(ByVal imgdata As String, ByVal FileName As String) As Integer

```
    'Find the path on the server of our apps images folder
    Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("images")

    'strip the path and .jpg etc out of our filename
    Dim i As Integer = InStrRev(FileName, "\")
    FileName = Mid(FileName, i)
    Dim j As Integer = InStr(FileName, ".") - 1
    Dim k As Integer = Len(FileName)
    FileName = Mid(FileName, 1, j)

    'Storing an image to bitmap after converting from base64 format'
    Dim Bm As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Base64ToImage(imgdata))

    'Convert the bitmap to a png and save it in our images folder
    BM.Save(FilePath & FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    'eventually we will create a database entry for this image and return the image ID
    Return 1
End Function

'For converting the base64 satring value into the image'
Public Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64String As String) As Image
    ' Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)

    ' Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
    Dim image__1 As Image = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    Return image__1
End Function
```

Please guys help- me out I'm working on it from the last 4 days.
Any Help is Appreciated. And Thanks In Advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest would be better in calling services from android. 
anyways if you want to do this your way you can send stream to your service make a method which takes stream.
and your android end ask connection for output stream and write all byte to it.

i have done this with Restful wcf.
for reference :
[Uploading MS Word files from Android to .Net WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860298/uploading-ms-word-files-from-android-to-net-wcf/8209430#8209430)